# Integral of a partial fraction function$\int\frac{1}{(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

How do we determine the integral
$$\int\frac{1}{(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}dx$$
My ideas are the followings:

1. We just split them into partial fractions like $$\frac{1}{(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{(x-1)^3}+\frac{D}{(x-2)}+\frac{E}{(x-2)^2}$$  But finding $A,B,C,D,E$ seems to be a really daunting task and the calculations will be huge.
2. I thought of substituting $x-1=u$ but that also doesn't help much since we again get the same form $\frac{1}{u^3(u-1)^2}$.

Is there any clever substitution to solve this? Trigonometric substitutions if possible are really helpful sometimes.

Comment: 1. is correct.  Solving a $5 \times 5$ system of linear equations with many coefficients equal to zero is not too bad.    (Especially one chosen by the problem poser so that the solution is all integers.)  Actually, finding $C$ is easy letting $x \to 1$ and similarly finding $E$ is easy.  So a $3 \times 3$ system remains.

Answer (score 5):

Here a clever substitution  $t=\frac{x-1}{x-2}$ to avoid the partial fraction
$$ \int \frac{1}{(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}dx
= \int \left(\frac1t-1\right)^3dt
$$

Comment: +1, I  too would have done it like this using Euler's transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the denominator to get
$$1=A(x-1)^2(x-2)^2+B(x-1)(x-2)^2+C(x-2)^2+D(x-1)^3(x-2)+E(x-1)^3. \tag1$$
Substituting $x=1$ yields
$1=C(1-2)^2$, so $C=1$.
Substituting $x=2$ yields
$1=E(2-1)^3$, so $E=1$.
Substituting $x=0$ yields
$$1=4A-4B+4C+2D-E=4A-4B+4+2D-1,$$ so
$$4A-4B+2D=-2. \tag2$$
Substituting $x=3$ yields
$$1 = 4A + 2B + C + 8D + 8E = 4A + 2B + 1 + 8D + 8,$$ so
$$4A + 2B + 8D = -8. \tag3$$
Comparing coefficients of $x^4$ in $(1)$ yields
$$0=A+D. \tag4$$
Now solve $(2)$ through $(4)$ to get $(A,B,D)=(3,2,-3)$.

Comment: Thank you but i actually came up with this approach as mentioned,i wanted a clever substitution to solve this instead of the lengthy calculations.

Comment: Did you take any of these shortcuts, or did you just multiply everything out?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, letting $y=x-1$ transform the integral into
$$\int \frac{1}{(x-1)^{3}(x-2)^{2}} d x=\int \frac{d y}{y^{3}(y-1)^{2}}$$

Repeatedly using $\frac{1}{y(y-1)}=\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y}$ resolving the integrate into partial fractions as

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{y^{3}(y-1)^{2}} &=\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{1}{y(y-1)}\right]^{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{y}\left(\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y}\right)^{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{y(y-1)^{2}}-\frac{2}{y^{2}(y-1)}+\frac{1}{y^{3}}\\&=\frac{1}{y(y-1)} \cdot \frac{1}{y-1} -\frac{2}{y} \cdot \frac{1}{y(y-1)}+\frac{1}{y^{3}}\\&=\frac{1}{(y-1)^{2}}-\frac{1}{y-1}+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{2}{y-1}+\frac{2}{y}+\frac{2}{y^{2}}+\frac{1}{y^{3}}\\&= \frac{3}{x-1}+\frac{2}{(x-1)^{2}}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^{3}}-\frac{3}{x-2}+\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
We can now conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int\left(\frac{3}{x-1}+\frac{2}{(x-1)^{2}}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^{3}}-\frac{3}{x-2}+\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2}}\right) d x \\
&=3 \ln |x-1|-\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{1}{2(x-1)^{2}}-3 \ln |x-2|-\frac{1}{x-2}+C\\
&=\frac{-6 x^{2}+15 x-8}{2(x-2)(x-1)^{2}}+3 \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x-2}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let $y=x-1$
$$
\frac{1}{y^{3}(y-1)^{2}}\equiv\frac{A}{y}+\frac{B}{y^{2}}+\frac{C}{y^{3}}+\frac{f(y)}{(y-1)^{2}},
$$
Then $$
1\equiv A y^{2}(y-1)^{2}+B y(y-1)^{2}+C(y-1)^{2}+y^{3} f(y) \tag*{(1)} 
$$
Putting $y=0$ gives $C=1$ and rearranging $(1)$ yields
$$
-y+2=A y(y-1)^{2}+B(y-1)^{2}+y^{2} f(y) \tag*{(2)} 
$$
Again, putting $y=0$ gives $B=2$ and rearranging $(2)$ yields
$$
-2 y+3=A(y-1)^{2}+y f(y) \tag*{(3)} 
$$
Again, putting $y=0$ gives $A=3$ and rearranging $(3)$ yields

$$
-2 y+3-3(y-1)^{2}=y f(y) \Rightarrow f(y)=-3y+4
$$
Putting back gives us its partial fractions
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{y^{3}(y-1)^{2}} &=\frac{3}{y}+\frac{2}{y^{2}}+\frac{1}{y^{3}}+\frac{-3 y+4}{(y-1)^{2}} \\
&=\frac{3}{y}+\frac{2}{y^{2}}+\frac{1}{y^{3}}-\frac{3}{y-1}+\frac{1}{(y-1)^{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int\left(\frac{3}{x-1}+\frac{2}{(x-1)^{2}}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^{3}}-\frac{3}{x-2}+\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2}}\right) d x \\
&=3 \ln |x-1|-\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{1}{2(x-1)^{2}}-3 \ln |x-2|-\frac{1}{x-2}+C\\
&=\frac{-6 x^{2}+15 x-8}{2(x-2)(x-1)^{2}}+3 \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x-2}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$